# Altering arrays in php from post to a session variable

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

a couple of days ago, I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416477/handle-multiple-inputs-of-a-form-in-php) and got a great response on how to handle the arrays. 
This was exactly what I needed

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key=>$name) {
  echo "Name: $name  Age: {$_POST['age'][$key]}";
}
```

the problem is, I need it not to print but to persist. Im making session variables like `$_SESSION["name"]= "some name";`

I wanna know how I can dump the POST array from above into a $SESSION[Array];
ultimately, to be able to re dump all of the data at will on any page. I need access to both $name in the array and the $age and I would like them to be associated.
In java I would do

```
String[][] something = new String[10][2]; //10 is size and 2 allows for name at index 0 and age at index 1.
```

Something  things to keep in mind. The size of the POST array is not set. They may be anywhere from 0 inputs to 100.

Along with saving the array, could you please tell me how to access it. Im use to java, so php arrays are new to me.

**EDIT**

After Trying johnps post

my page looks like this

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key=>$name) {
  echo "Name: $name  Age: {$_POST['age'][$key]} <br/>";
     $_SESSION['post_data'][$key] = $name;
     $_SESSION['post_data'][$key] = $_POST['age'];
    echo $key; 
}
```

and the output on the page is

```
Name: The name potion Age: adult
1
```

However, Ive tried the following to get "The Name Position" as output and nothing is working

```
echo $_SESSION['post_data']['name'];//doesnt have an output
echo $_SESSION['post_data'][$key];//out puts "Array" and nothing else
```

I would like the output to be
The name Position, Adult. 
Just like the foreach loop is doing right now, but from a 2d array. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a multi dimensional array just as easily in PHP. The reason your example doesn't work is because it keeps overriding the same index

```
//Assuming your POST data consists of age => name pairs, you store it like this
$_SESSION['post_data'] = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $age => $name) {
   $_SESSION['post_data'][$count]['age']  = $age;
   $_SESSION['post_data'][$count]['name'] = $name;
   $count++;
}
```

And to access it, simply iterate over it or use the key

```
//iterating
foreach ($_SESSION['post_data'] as $person) {
     echo "Name: {$person['name']}  Age: {$person['age']} <br/>";
}

//using the key
echo $_SESSION['post_data'][0]['age']; //print the first person's age
echo $_SESSION['post_data'][0]['name']; //print the first person's name
```

Visually your data looks like this (example)

```
array(
  0 => array(
    age  => 12,
    name => jane
  ),
  1 => array(
    age  => 18,
    name => jack
  ),
  2 => array(
    age  => 25,
    name => jones
  ),
)
```

Comment: and how would i add the $age to it with the same key. so i can recall it like you posted in "to access it" but also be able to access age for the same name (Person)

Comment: I've updated the answer. But it's the same principle, as long as you have the key you can go to any level in an array.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but should i add that data in the foreach loop. Since its being pasted true or false from the post?

Comment: Yes, you can add it in the loop. And instead of looping the POST variable, you'd just loop the SESSION variable with $age=>$name

Comment: JohnP Ive update my post to better outline what I need. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can directly store `$_POST['name']` to `$_SESSION["name"]` and it will persist,

```
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['name']
```